# Python 2 - Division times 10 returns 0 everytime

Tags: python-2.7

When the program divides two user inputted numbers, then times that, the program returns 0 every time

```
correct = input("User, Input the amount of correct answers. :")
points_possible = input("User, Input the amount of points possible. :")

score = correct / points_possible
grade = score * 10

print grade
```

The expected output

```
if (1/2) * 10 = 5, but will output 0
```

Comment: what happens when you do print(1/2)

Comment: 0 is the result

Comment: and 10 * 0 = 0 so your code works as intended

Comment: I understand why. I needed it to make a float because an interger is only a real number and a float allows for decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.7 version, the input that would be taken from the console would always be in the form of strings. So, you'll need to convert it to integers.

```py
#code in Python 3.5
correct = int(input("User, Input the amount of correct answers. :"))
points_possible = int(input("User, Input the amount of points possible. :"))

score = correct / points_possible
grade = score * 10

print(grade)
```

The reason why you're just getting `0` in Python 2 is that if integers are given then you'll get integer division only. If you want float division, you need to make sure there is a decimal point somewhere so that Python knows it doesn't have to truncate the value to an `int`.

```py
#code in Python 2.7
correct = float(raw_input("User, Input the amount of correct answers. :"))
points_possible = float(raw_input("User, Input the amount of points possible. :"))

score = correct / points_possible
grade = score * 10.0

print grade
```

Comment: Because in Python 2, if you try 2/5 (or try to divide any two integers for that matter), you'll get only the answer before the decimal point. That means 1/2 = 0.5 however, you'll get 0. So, if you try 1.0/2.0 or 1.0/2 or 1/2.0 (any one can  be float) then you'll be 0.5.

Comment: Thank you so much! I overlooked that the floats allow for decimals and intergers only allow for real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

it's because python needs you to make it understand that you divide by a float: you can either add .0 at the end of the diviser or type 10/float(2)